# Can't install custom SailsJS adapter

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js

Every time I try to use an adapter other than sails-disk I'll get a `No find() method defined in adapter!` Error. 
My sails app will lift fine, but when ever I get to a point where the adapter is being called it fails. I've tried several different adapters and they all fail.

I'm using the boilerplate config files.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. What does your call to adapters look like? What about your directory structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem too and only happened with custom adapters. So instead of using the path `api/adapters`, i moved the adapter to `node_modules` where others adapters such as `sails-mongo` are installed, and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

usually, you just need to enable your new adapter in `yourapp/config/adapters.js`

For exemple, with mongo :

- add `sails-mongo` dependence in your package.json file

  ```
  "dependencies": {
      ...
      "sails-mongo": "~0.9.6"
  }
  ```
- run `$ npm install`
- change your config file (ie: `yourapp/config/adapters.js`) by editing :

  ```
  module.exports.adapters = {

    'default': 'mongo',

    mongo: {
      module: 'sails-mongo',
      host: 'localhost',
      user: '',
      password: '',
      database: 'your-prod-db'
    }
  };
  ```
- Of course for local dev, edit `yourapp/config/local.js` like:

  ```
  adapters : {

      'default': 'mongo',

      mongo: {
        module: 'sails-mongo',
        host: 'localhost',
        user: '',
        password: '',
        database: 'your-local-db'
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is there a way to use a *custom* adapter without publishing it through npm? Maybe for development purposes?

Comment: Yes, see the .gitignore file, who disable `config/local.js` by default. For production purposes, you can also use `process.env` variables. If it can help, i found this morning some interesting tutorials by "irl nathan" here: http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/archives/

Comment: If you add your custom adapter to the `api/adapters` folder and call it `<module>Adapter.js` where `<module>` is the string you used when defining it in the `config/adapters.js` it will find it and work.